# rxjs: Index and condition inside a map function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have created an observable from a JSON array, I want to add new values for each element inside the array, and I need to do it based on the index of the element.

So far I'm only able to add same key-value for all the elements. Is there a way to introduce index into map function? So for example I can say that for the first element "is_leader" is true, and for all the others it's false.

Code so far:

```js
this.dataSubscription = this.dataService.getTestData().subscribe(
  res => {
    this.allData = res.map(data => {
      data['is_leader'] = true;  // Here I would like a condition
      return data;
    });
  }
);
```

Working in Angular 2.

Comment: the map funtion have 3 arguments, first is object, second is index and last is array

Comment: Instead of an observable, can you use a BehaviorSubject which will allow you to set the first element?

Comment: @jrelo thanks, didn't know that. How does one read it out from this documentation? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
this.dataSubscription = this.dataService.getTestData().subscribe(res => this.allData = res.map((data, index) => {
        data['is_leader'] = index === 0;
        return data;
    })
);
```

Comment: Tnx, this works. Can you explain this part though? data['is_leader'] = index === 0; I see that it means that if index === 0, then it's true. Where can I find documentation for this kind of "simplified" code?